# Android Lock Orientation and Double Create

Tags: android, android-orientation

I want to make my application displayed only in portrait orientation, so I have put `android:screenOrientation="portrait"` in the `Activity` tag in `AndroidManifest.xml`, and have put `setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);` in the Activity's `onCreate` method.

This works to lock the orientation to portrait, however, when the Activity starts, it shows itself once, then shows itself again, so you see a sort of flash. I can confirm that `onCreate` is being called twice as well.

This flash is causing further force closes later in my application.

How can I eliminate this flash?

#### Edit

I had a splash screen displaying before the activity I had described. It was being run twice, and therefore ran this activity twice (via an Intent) twice. I fixed this issue by checking if this activity had already been stared using an intent in the splash screen class, and it had, not to run it again. The fix was more of a workaround than a fix, but I hope it helps people.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that using the Activity's `configChanges` attribute (in the manifest) should solve your problem. [ConfigChanges attribute documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#config)

*However*, you are just going around another problem. What you really should address is *why* is that provoking FC? There is absolutely no reason for that to happen so you also should solve that problem. More info in [handling runtime changes](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/runtime-changes.html).

Please note: using the first approach is acceptable to address the performance/UX issues though.

Just in case you wonder why `onCreate` is called twice, once I got into this problem and I think that it was related to having the orientation fixed and then having another activity being created but in a different orientation. Before the second activity was started, the former activity changed into the orientation of the latter. And remember that keyguard is also an Activity! I'm not sure if this happens for this reason though.

Comment: I have tried that, and `onConfigurationChanged()` is not called if I add `android:configChanges="orienation|keybaordHidden"`, nor does my application cease to have the flashing issue.

Comment: To your suggestion about a previous activity: I do have a splash screen activity running before this, and it calls this Activity via Intent. However the splash screen is coded in the same way to lock the orientation (note that it does not flash like this activity does)

Comment: which flags do you send to these activities? (both via intents, in the manifest and in onCreate?)

Answer (score 1):

don't put : "setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);".
Just let the AndroidManifest do his job. I thing what you did is :

1. Tell your App to go only in Portrait mode
2. Tell your Activity to be in Portrait mode, wherever it was already like this or not (The flash have to come from this).
3. I could be wrong.

Comment: I have commented out `setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);` and the flash persists.

Comment: I have tried with and without `android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"`