# Splash Screen activity runs twice

Tags: java, android, http-post, splash-screen

So basically this is the class that starts at the launch of the app and it shows a splashscreen while getting a serverList from a server, once it has the list, it starts the next activity, the problem is that this activity seems to be getting called twice before the next activity is started, what could be causing that?

```
 public class SplashScreen extends Activity {

public static DefaultHttpClient httpClient;

private String resp;
static String res;
private String errorMsg;

 final Context context = this;
public static String cookieValue;
public static Cookie cookie;
String now_playing, earned;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash_screen);


    String Wlcclient = "Yes";
    String ClientType = "Android";
    String Version = "0.103";

    new PrefetchData().execute(Wlcclient,ClientType,Version);
}


    public static String executeHttpPost(String url, ArrayList<NameValuePair> postParameters) throws Exception {
    BufferedReader in = null;
    try {


        SplashScreen.httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();                               
        HttpPost request = new HttpPost(url);                           
        UrlEncodedFormEntity formEntity = new UrlEncodedFormEntity(postParameters);
        request.setEntity(formEntity);



        HttpResponse response = SplashScreen.httpClient.execute(request);
       List<Cookie> cookies = SplashScreen.httpClient.getCookieStore().getCookies();

        cookie = cookies.get(0);
       cookieValue = "ASPSESSIONIDCQTCRACT=" + cookie.getValue();


        System.out.println("COOK" + cookieValue);
        Header[] headers = response.getAllHeaders();
        System.out.println("length" + headers.length);
        for (int i=0; i < headers.length; i++) {

            Header h = headers[i];

            System.out.println( "Header names: "+h.getName());
            System.out.println(  "Header Value: "+h.getValue());
        }

        CookieManager cookieManager = CookieManager.getInstance();




        in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent()));


        StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer("");
        String line = "";
        String NL = System.getProperty("line.separator");
        while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(line + NL);
        }
        in.close();



        String result = sb.toString();
        return result;

    }
    finally {
        if (in != null) {
            try {
                in.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}


 public class PrefetchData extends AsyncTask<String,Void,String> {

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        // before making http calls         

    }

@Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

        ArrayList<NameValuePair> postParameters = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        postParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("WlcClient",
                params[0]));    // params[0] contains the first value that you have passed and params[1] second value.
        postParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("ClientType",
                params[1]));
        postParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Version",
                params[2]));

        String response = null;
        try {
            response = 
               executeHttpPost(server,
                            postParameters);
             res = response.toString();

            resp = res.replaceAll("\\s+", "");
            System.out.println(res);


            //resultt =res;
             return res;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            errorMsg = e.getMessage();
        }
        return res;
 }    // end of doInBackground



    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        // After completing http call
        // will close this activity and lauch main activity
        Intent i = new Intent(SplashScreen.this, LoginLayout.class);

        startActivity(i);

        // close this activity
        finish();
    }



}
```

}

Comment: Do you mean that onCreate is called twice?

Comment: Not sure, i know the executeHttpPost is being called twice because i get two different System.out's of the header list, does calling oncreate also call the methods in the class?

Comment: I also see the main activity load twice when launching the app, showing that it is executing that part of transition twice as well

Comment: In any of the calls that execute twice, print out a stack trace and see where it's being called from.

Comment: Check this out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7084695/android-lock-orientation-and-double-create

Comment: could you explain that ajw? what is a stack trace?

Answer (score 1):

inside onCreate() of SplashScreenActivity
I've replaced finish() with onDestroy() after startActivity(intent)

```java
    
    public class SplashScreenActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    
        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash_screen);
    
    
    
            new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).postDelayed(new Runnable(){
                @Override
                public void run() {
    
                    Intent intent;
    
                    intent = new Intent(SplashScreenActivity.this,MainActivity.class);
    
    
                    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
                    startActivity(intent);
    
    //here we call the onDestory instead of finish()
                    onDestroy();
                }
            }, 1000);
    
        }
    }
```

worked for me

Comment: it works, but do you have any idea why is it happening when using finish?